# ViewPager + Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, picasso

I'm creating a Image Slider using Picasso + Viewpager.
I am able to swipe the slider base on the image size(counts).
But no images has been loaded tho i can swipe the screen.
What is wrong with my codes?

In my MainActivity,
I get the links of my images.
then set the adapter Like this.

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,IMAGES);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

IMAGES=Arrays of Links(For images).

My ImagePager_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plusbtn"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here i declared my ViewPager..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

And for My Adapter..

```
package com.thesis.juandirection.picasso;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Galvez on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private  Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> IMAGES = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> IMAGES) {
        this.IMAGES = IMAGES;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagepager_layout,null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(IMAGES.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.plusbtn)
                .centerCrop()
                .fit()
                .into(img);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your image links correct? If correct, did you try to remove ".centerCrop().fit()" part from your picasso loading codes. I have faced with similar problem before.

Comment: I tried to remove centerCrop.fit but its not working. Yep the links are correct. I even tried to put image from drawable to a viewpager but still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should change this;

```
@Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }
```

to this;

```
@Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }
```

Comment: I am facing similar problem. I am using same as your solution but still not solved

Answer (score 2):

As @cemtufekci advised, you have to change `isViewFromObject` accordingly. 
But it will not fix images loading problem, if you don't have appropriate 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.