# I'm trying to show images from firebase into a carousal view using a ViewPager and picasso but Images are not coming into view

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager

Images from firebase are not coming into view

I have tried everything I could, in the end, I had to ask the question

Here is my adapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
public  String[] imageUrls ;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,String[] imageUrls){
this.context=context;
this.imageUrls=imageUrls;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageUrls.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view==o;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    container.addView(imageView);

    return imageView;



}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
}
```

here is my other class from where I'm getting data from firebase

```
private void loadImages(String insideHostelID) {


    ImageDatabaseReference.child(insideHostelID).child("INSIDE_PICTURES").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Inside_location inside_location=dataSnapshot.getValue(Inside_location.class) ;
          //  Toast.makeText(hostelDetails.this,""+ inside_location.getPIC9(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            imageUrls = new String[]{
                    inside_location.getPIC1(), inside_location.getPIC2(),
                    inside_location.getPIC3(), inside_location.getPIC4(),
                    inside_location.getPIC5(), inside_location.getPIC6(),
                    inside_location.getPIC7(), inside_location.getPIC8(),
                    inside_location.getPIC9(), inside_location.getPIC10(),
            };
            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getBaseContext(),imageUrls);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    insideHostelImage.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up adapter before getting any response from firebase.
Just modified code like below.

```
private void loadImages(String insideHostelID) {    
    ImageDatabaseReference.child(insideHostelID).child("INSIDE_PICTURES").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Inside_location inside_location=dataSnapshot.getValue(Inside_location.class) ;
          //  Toast.makeText(hostelDetails.this,""+ inside_location.getPIC9(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            imageUrls = new String[]{
                    inside_location.getPIC1(), inside_location.getPIC2(),
                    inside_location.getPIC3(), inside_location.getPIC4(),
                    inside_location.getPIC5(), inside_location.getPIC6(),
                    inside_location.getPIC7(), inside_location.getPIC8(),
                    inside_location.getPIC9(), inside_location.getPIC10(),
            };
            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getBaseContext(),imageUrls);
            insideHostelImage.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

And add/replace below method in adapter class.

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

Comment: Still no images

Comment: Make sure your query response returns data properly and also add some toast in "onCancelled" method of query. So that you will notify when database drop your request.

Comment: checked everything no images still

Comment: If you are getting any data in response from firebase. Then try changing addView method in adapter to 
`container.addView(imageView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_CONTENT, MATCH_CONTENT));`

Comment: tried STILL no images IS THERE ANY TUTORIAL OUT FOR THIS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597312/viewpager-picasso      This Question helped me to solve my problem

Comment: Good to here that. I edited my answer base on that. Enjoy coding. [:thumb_up]